# Discord.js editing embed description problem

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this discord.js bot which sends an embed message and adds a value to it's description on command and deletes the value after 5 seconds, but every time I add a value to the description when it has already a value in it, the value that I add disappears when the first value gets deleted after those 5 seconds.

here is my code:

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] })

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(/*db adress*/, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const embedSchema = new Schema({
    exists: { type: String, required: true },
    embedId: { type: String, required: true },
    channelId: { type: String, required: true }
})

const Embed = mongoose.model('Embed', embedSchema, 'embed')

const embedMessage = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription('empty')

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.content === '.sendEmbed') {
        const embed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedMessage] })

        const saveEmbed = new Embed({
            exists: 'true',
            embedId: embed.id,
            channelId: message.channel.id
        })
        saveEmbed.save()
    } else if (message.content.startsWith('.add')) {
        const wordsInMessage = message.content.split(' ')

        if (!wordsInMessage[2]) {
            Embed.find({ exists: 'true' }, async (err, embed) => {
                const word = wordsInMessage[1]
                const oldEmbed = await message.channel.messages.fetch(embed[0].embedId)

                const newEmbed = oldEmbed.embeds[0]
                const embedDescription = newEmbed.description.replaceAll('empty', '')

                newEmbed.setDescription(`${embedDescription}\n${word}`)
                oldEmbed.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed] })

                setTimeout(() => updateValue(word), 5000)
            })
        }
    }
})

function updateValue(word) {
    Embed.find({ exists: 'true' }, async (err, embed) => {
        Array.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
            if (index >= this.length) {
                return this.valueOf()
            }
        
            return this.splice(0, index) + replacement + this.splice(index + 1)
        }

        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(embed[0].channelId)
        const getEmbed = await channel.messages.fetch(embed[0].embedId)

        const embedMessage = await getEmbed.embeds[0]

        const wordsPosition = embedMessage.description.split('\n').indexOf(word)
        const newValue = embedMessage.description.split('\n')[wordsPosition].split(' ').replaceAt(0, 'empty')

        embedMessage.setDescription(`${newValue}`)
        getEmbed.edit({ embeds: [embedMessage] })
    })
}

client.login(/*bot token*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

- I'm guessing that you want to edit the description of an existing embed

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Schema = require("path-to-schema");

const data = await Schema.find({ exists: true });
const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(data.embedId);
if(!msg && !msg.embeds) return;
const oldEmbed = msg.embeds[0];
const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed(oldEmbed.toJSON()).setDescription("new description with existing embed details");
await msg.edit({ embeds: [newEmbed] });
```

- **Details**:

So the above code basically fetches the message ID from your `Schema` and fetches the message in the current channel. It creates a new Embed with the existing embed's JSON and updates the description, ultimately updating the old message.